My flutter app is getting built but now displaying output on emulator
I am currently following a tutorial. It's working on his end, but not working on my end. VS Code is not showing any errors.
The debug console shows the following.
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
√ Built build\windows\x64\runner\Debug\nlp.exe
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(147)] Could not prepare isolate.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(549)] Could not create root isolate.
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(690)] Could not launch engine with configuration.

Main.dart file code :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}


The issue seems to be with your code, specifically in the MaterialApp widget within your _HomeScreenState class. You are using HomeScreen as the home property of MaterialApp, which creates an infinite recursive loop.
Here’s why it’s happening:

HomeScreen creates a MaterialApp widget.
The MaterialApp widget sets its home to another instance of HomeScreen.
This recursion keeps going, causing the app to crash.

Try with below code and run,
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Welcome to the Home Screen!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}


Is this from Chatgpt, Perplexity.ai ?
Coz it was giving mesomething like the same thing above.
I don't want to change my home screen view

It doesn't matter - share your whole code with main()

Looks like you have missed the main function with runApp() method which is used to initialize and run the app.that is basically the root of your project.
add this to your main.dart
    void main() async {
     
      runApp(Config());
    }
    
    class Config extends StatefulWidget {
      const Config({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<Config> createState() => _ConfigState();
    }
    
    class _ConfigState extends State<Config> {
      @override
      void initState() {
      
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
      }
       
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          builder: (context, child) {
          home: HomeScreen(), //your first root widget class
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        );
      }
    }


I'm getting stack overflow error.

It's giving lots of errors

You seem to be missing the main function which is the entry point and runApp function responsible for launching the app:

main() is the entry point of the app. main() is responsible for launching the app by calling runApp().


The runApp() function takes a widget (usually MaterialApp) and inflates it to display the initial UI on the screen.

Also i noticed you are calling the same class in MaterialApp>home which is not possible to do. Below is your code modified and corrected:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const HomeScreen());
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   const HomeScreen({super.key});

   @override
   State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        //home: HomeScreen(), //REQUIRE TO CHANGE THIS TO ANOTHER CLASS
        home: const NewScreen(),
      );
   }
}

Here is the link to better understand main function and different variations.

What is New screen() ?

It's a stateless OR stateful class name which will contain all your widgets. You can name it anything.
